# Java - Need Parse Help for dollar amounts

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm trying to figure out a way to parse the "$" and "," out of a dollar amount.

For example, say I have a String that is $5,600.  I need to parse it so what I have left is just 5600.  Any help is great appreciated.

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

```
 NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
 Number number = format.parse("$5,600");
```

`number` will be `5600`

You can specify a locale if you want to target special countries.

Comment: Hey Mohamed, do you have a chat/IM line I can chat with you about some extension question I have?

Answer (score 4):

In principle, you can do the following two steps:

1. Remove the leading `$` (if any).
2. Remove any embedded commas.

Optionally, you can then check to make sure that what you're left with is all digits.

You can do this using the `startsWith`, `substring`, and `replace` methods of [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), but there are many ways you could go about it.

Comment: The replace method is like reinventing the wheel that already exists with `Format`. The solution stated by others uses "Java" to extract the number symbols without doing any replace. For example, the replace method will not work for any other locale but US. In my honest opinion, you should use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance` and parse the string into a Number. Which is the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `DecimalFormat`?  Remember, the `Format` classes can be used for string parsing as well as string formatting.